# Search data in database via tags in c#

Tags: c#

I have this list of movies in my database. I want to search some movies using their tags.

Ex.:

- Scary movie I - tags are "horror, comedy, scary movie, ghosts"
- Saw III -  tags are "horror, saw, "
- Ghost House tags are "horror, ghosts"
  *etc.

When I search `"ghosts"` the result should return to *Scary movie I*, *Ghost House*, etc.(return to the list of movie having same tags)

```
"SELECT movie_name FROM table_movie WHERE tags = " + movie_tags + ";"
```

Comment: Can you post some code (show what you've tried so far?)

Comment: There is no question in Your question.

Comment: "SELECT movie_name FROM tablemovie WHERE tags='ghosts' " I want to search "ghost" and i want to have all list of movies that have ghost tags @PrashanthThurairatnam

Comment: I just don't know where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should start with database schema. Tags as text note are bad decision, database would not be normalized and searching would be inefficient.

Make three tables, something like:

```
Tag(tagID primaryKey, tagName)    
Movie(movieID primaryKey, movieName)
TagMovie(tagID foreignKey, movieID foreingKey)
```

Don't forget on unique constraint on (tagID, movieID) - make the tuple primary key and You are done.

You can then search it like

```
SELECT Movie.* FROM Movie 
JOIN TagMovie ON Movie.movieID = TagMovie.movieID
JOIN Tag ON Tag.tagID = TagMovie.tagID
WHERE Tag.tagName = "ghosts"
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the question you have asked your solution will be:

You need to write a string that will end up like the following query statement

`SELECT movie_name FROM table_movie WHERE tags like '%ghosts%'`

Although the approach you are using is not efficient. You should change your structure.